# Font-awesome: how does it use class names to affect its content?

Tags: html, css, less, font-awesome

I'm trying to build a program that can utilize a classname for its data
(i.e. if class="hero-banner-80" I could use the 80 as its width) and I was wondering how font-awesome does it? It uses its class-name to decide which char to place inside its element, and reading the src code didn't help me.

Comment: forgot to mention - without js if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is no way to dynamically parse a class and generate rules based on some portion of it with an arbitrary value, as you seem to want to do. But you could put the width in a data attribute, as follows:

```html
<div class="hero-banner" data-width="80px">
```

```css
[data-width] {
    width: attr(data-width);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea, but that is just a very long way around just putting `style="width: 80px;"`

Comment: and @SeanStopnik the width is not set - you can't hardcode it

Comment: +1, though the answer should have a remark that almost no browser supports this for anything but `content` [these days](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

It uses pseudo classes on each icon, with the unicode of the icon as the content.  The size of the icon is inherited by the font-size of the parent.

Comment: :before, :after....  in the CSS.  If you do not know what that is, I'd suggest do some research on Google.

Comment: so in short, it is possible to do what I'm asking?

Comment: Im not really sure what you are asking here?  You asked how font-awesome works.  But what you are trying to build sounds nothing like that??  What you need is just css...  `.hero-banner-80: width: 80px;`.

Comment: I think font-awesome doesn't end up doing what I thought it did. What I need is for the css to dynmically change that width **depending** on what the classname is - so if the classname is "hero-banner-60" the width is now 60

Comment: @javatripping CSS is static. You can't *dynamically* generate/modify properties/content depending on class names there. With preprocessors like Less you can generate thousands of classes in one line of course but it's still the same static CSS in the end.

Comment: @seven-phases-max yep, I know - but like you said in your comment about font-awesome, less can programmatically create css (on the server) to fit variable classnames - I'm starting to think I horribly worded my question

Comment: @javatripping Well, [`[less] loop` query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bless%5d%20loop) can provide some examples. Also language docs is usually [a good start](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is just basic CSS:

```
.hero-banner-40 {
    width: 40px;
}

.hero-banner-60 {
    width: 60px;
}

.hero-banner-80 {
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: not really - if you change the classname on the html - I was hoping the css could change the width accordingly - not by hard-coding the width

Comment: Huh??  Do you not understand how CSS works?  If you change the class on the html element, it will use the matching css in the stylesheet.  If you do not understand that...  then this is as far as I go with trying to help.  I would suggest reading up on html/css.

Comment: the reason I can't hardcode the classes are is bc there is a 255^(16) combo of classnames - not viable for hardcoding obvs

Comment: I know exactly how html/css works - I'm trying to see if there is a css processor like less that can do what I'm asking when the server loads the page. I'm not asking for magic

Comment: Well I have no idea what you are needing then.  If you are letting users make up their own class names, or if there are that many random class name combinations, then I don't know what to say.  Maybe just add inline styles based on what someone enters.  I really have no idea what you are trying to build.  Good luck...